# Ошибка "pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed"

Tags: gulp, npm

[image: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed]

Как исправить данную ошибку, что установить

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`

Comment: Как я понимаю `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev` - команда для mac! Для windows я прописываю так `npm i apt-get install libpng-dev` или `npm install libpng-dev`, в обеих случаях выдаться ошибка

Comment: или попробовать установить https://pngquant.org/pngquant-windows.zip. или попробовать в cmd запущенной под админом выполнить `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`, потом удалить node_modules и попробовать собрать снова https://stackoverflow.com/q/26522310/4496422. у меня нет винды под рукой, не могу подтвердить что лучше

Comment: после установки всего через `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` сборка прошла как и раньше, то есть успешно! Самому интересно, почему раньше работало все без этих доп. инструментов? !!!! И еще хотел бы спросить про такую ошибку - `gyp ERR! find Python... ну и далее портянка из типичных стрик ! ` Эта ошибка не влияет на сборку!  Что я только не делал что бы исчезала эта ошибка но увы! Есть советы как решить?

Comment: погугли. если не нагуглится - создай отдельный вопрос с полным листингом "типичных стрик"

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/26522310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, для сборки и установки не хватает `windows build tools`.

#### Для Windows

Нужно запустить `cmd` или `Windows Power Shell` **под Администратором** установить `windows build tools`.

```bsh
$ npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Удалить `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, `yarn.lock` в каталоге, где ранее выполнялась сборка.

Повторить установку модулей в вашем приложении

```bsh
$ npm install
```

---

#### Для Linux

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```